# Select an option from a datalist and compare index number to another option in a second datalist

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, datalist

Sorry for the confusing title. What I have is two table columns next to each other, and in each are datalists . One is a list of course titles offered at a school, the other is the corresponding catalog numbers for the courses.

What I want to have happen is students can select the course title and it will automatically display the catalog number in the next column, or they can select the catalog number and it will display the course title in the previous column.

How I have this data set up currently is 2 separate arrays, like so:

```
<td>
    <input list="courses" name="course" placeholder="Course" onchange="indexTest()">
      <datalist id="courses">
       <!--Filled in script-->
      </datalist>
</td>
<td>
    <input list="catalogs" name="catalog" placeholder="Catalog Number">
      <datalist id="catalogs">
       <!--Filled in script-->
      </datalist>
</td>

    <script>
        var course = ["class 1","class 2","class 3","class 4","class 5"];
        var list = document.getElementById('courses');

        courseNames.forEach(function(item){
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = item;
          list.appendChild(option);
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        var catalog = ["catalog 1", "catalog 2","catalog 3","catalog 4","catalog 5"];
        var list = document.getElementById('catalogs');

        catNumbers.forEach(function(item){
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = item;
          list.appendChild(option);
    });
    </script>
```

I thought possibly I could run a script that looked up the index number of the selected option in one array and pulled the same index number from the other array, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both arrays will have the corresponding values in the same indecies, you can just do this in your onchange events for each drop down:

Side note datalist is not supported in Safari or IE Version <= 9, may want to change to a select element:

```
<select id="courses" onchange="UpdateFromCourses()">

</select>

//Just make another function like this doing 
//the same thing but to the other drop down

 function UpdateFromCourses(){
    const selIndex = document.getElementById('courses').selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById('catalogs').selectedIndex = selIndex;
 }
```

Comment: This is great! The only problem with the select element is it doesn't seem to allow people to type in their selections and dynamically update the list to match their input. These lists will contain hundreds of classes and I don't particularly want people scrolling for years.

Comment: @Doodlebug You can attach events to the input boxes which could then filter your drop downs, so for input name="course" you could add an event for onkeyup and write a function which takes the value in the input and filters down the drop down list.